# Is it possible to check if checked out from a specific repository in a Jenkins declarative pipeline?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I would like to have a release stage in my Jenkinsfile that only runs when it's checked out from the original repository. This is to avoid error messages on cloned repositories, because of missing keys etc. there.

```
stage('Release')
 {
  when
   {
    allOf 
     {
      // TODO Check for repository url https://github.com/PowerStat/TemplateEngine.git
      branch 'master'
     }
   }
  steps
   {
    script
     {
      if (isUnix()) 
       {           
        sh 'mvn --batch-mode release:clean'
        sh 'mvn --batch-mode release:prepare'
        sh 'mvn --batch-mode release:perform'
       }
      else
       {
        bat 'mvn --batch-mode release:clean'
        bat 'mvn --batch-mode release:prepare'
        bat 'mvn --batch-mode release:perform'
       }
     }
   }
 }
```

I have studied [Pipeline Syntax: when](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#when) but have no idea how to do the test I would like to have.

Also I thought about using an environment variable [Global Variable Reference](https://opensource.triology.de/jenkins/pipeline-syntax/globals), but found non with the repository URL in it.

So my question is: how to implement this check in a decalarative pipeline?

Answer (score 1):

You can get remote repository URL from `git config remote.origin.url` command. You can execute this command using `expression` directive inside the `when` block - it defines a closure that returns a `boolean` value.

Consider the following example:

```groovy
def expectedRemoteUrl = "https://github.com/PowerStat/TemplateEngine.git"

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Release") {
            when {
                allOf {
                    branch 'tmp'
                    expression {
                        def remoteUrl = isUnix() ?
                            sh(script: "git config remote.origin.url", returnStdout: true)?.trim() :
                            bat(script: "git config remote.origin.url", returnStdout: true)?.trim()

                        return expectedRemoteUrl == remoteUrl
                    }
                }
            }

            steps {
                echo "Do your release steps here..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if `git` command is not available in the node that runs the pipeline, you can get the remote repository URL with `scm.userRemoteConfigs?.first()?.url`. Consider the following example:

```groovy
def expectedRemoteUrl = "https://github.com/PowerStat/TemplateEngine.git"

pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Release") {
            when {
                allOf {
                    branch 'tmp'
                    expression {
                        def remoteUrl = scm.userRemoteConfigs?.first()?.url

                        return expectedRemoteUrl == remoteUrl
                    }
                }
            }

            steps {
                echo "Do your release steps here..."
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try this. Also I made a feature request at Jenkins because I would like to have this independend of the version control system. https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-58366

Comment: I'm not sure if this expectation is valid. You run the build pipeline from the single repository, so there is no space for mixing two (or more) VCS systems in a single pipeline. Jenkins pipeline exposes an object `scm` (you can do `println scm.dump()` inside your pipeline to investigate it). There is no common API representing repository URL - you can compare `GitSCM` (https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/git/hudson/plugins/git/GitSCM.html) with `SubversionSCM` (https://github.com/jenkinsci/subversion-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/hudson/scm/SubversionSCM.java).

Comment: For simplicity, you can always define `git config remote.origin.url` command in a shared variable, so you can access it from a single place. But I wouldn't expect having such information (repository URL) exposed implicitly. The parent `SCM` class does not define such property - https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/scm/SCM.html I can guess the authors designed it like that for a reason.

Comment: Just to make it clear, I don't want to mix two or more vcs systems in a single pipeline - I only want to have an (vcs) independent solution that could be reused with every vcs.

Comment: Whatever I do (path, tool setting, ...), I get `git command not found`.

Comment: @PowerStat, it looks like your worker node has no git client installed. There is an alternative way to receive the repo URL. Please take a look at the updated answer.

Comment: I have installed git and it's in the windows path (all users) - could execute on the commandline without problems.

Comment: Ok the second variant ends in `Scripts not permitted to use method hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM getUserRemoteConfigs.`

Comment: Jenkins sandbox mode requires white listing almost every method you are trying to use. Go to scripts approval page and approve usage of this method if you want to use this approach.

Comment: I think sandbox mode is not a problem for me - it would be also ok for closed-source-projects - but I think it is not a good idea for open-source projects that might be used by people that are not so familar with Jenkins.

Comment: I was referring to Jenkins Groovy sandbox mode. When enabled, it requires white listing Groovy methods used in the pipeline script. Some of them are white listed by default, but it is just a small subset of all possible methods. It happens all the time when you script the pipeline using plain Groovy that you have to approve methods usage - sometimes it confuses people because they wrongly assume that approving Groovy methods is something bad. It is not. Jenkins let you know which methods may introduce vulnerabilities. The one showed above is safe to use.